# Get information or properties of COM objects

Tags: c#, api, winapi, object, com

I am writing a tool where I have some COM Component (for example a DLL) with a manifest file (Sxs / RegFree). My Tool iterates through all Class-IDs and should check if I it can create an instance with this Class-ID.

BUT, there are some problems. Some of the COM Objects (Classes) are programmed in a way, that I cannot create an instance because it's simly forbidden.

In one of my iterations my tool crashes, because it wants to crate an instance from an object where it is forbidden. Even a try ... catch does not help. When debugging with Visual Studio 2013, I get the information, that there were an error with the heap.

So my question is: It is somehow possible, to get some information about the COM Object, for example, if someone can create an instance from this Class-ID before creating an instance?

**EDIT:** Here is the code where I am creating the instance:

```
var clsid = new Guid(guid);
Guid IID_IUnknown = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
object instance = null;
hResult = CoCreateInstance(ref clsid, null, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, ref IID_IUnknown, out instance);
if (hResult > 0x7FFFFFFF)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Many problems with this approach.  But certainly first and foremost, [you are doing it wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27946718/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant: No, that is not the solution. My manifest are working, because I can create instances for a lot of class ID's. But there is a special Class-ID with a class where I get a heap error. But the DLL is loaded, because I can create instances from the same DLL but with other Class-ID's.

Comment: I didn't propose a solution, just pointed out that you were doing it wrong.  There is no point in pursuing this approach, such a COM component can never work in practice.  Whatever else you are doing must be very wrong as well, "heap errors" are very nasty bugs.

Comment: @HansPassant: I added my C#-Code above, where I want to create the instance. The given GUID normally creates an instance from that COM Object. Without any errors. But with a special GUID I get a heap error. But when I do something wrong (and sorry for that, I don't know what), how do it correct?

Comment: No point in doing it that way when you can use Type.GetTypeFromCLSID().  Diagnosing heap errors requires debugging the native code.

Comment: If you are getting a heap error, then there is a bug in the DLL. Contact the vendor.

Answer (score -1):

Some CLSID do not have direct access, it is for COM System only when real objects are created.
Whem you create an object like "VBScript" CLSID:
"{B54F3741-5B07-11CF-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}"
COM automaticaly create another object for internal use like that:
{00000323-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} (CLSID_StdGlobalInterfaceTable)
Like this last have many others for administration only.
See ones: 
[Standards Assignments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc226820.aspx)